# Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected Identifier

Tags: javascript

I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected Identifier

```
{% extends 'tweets/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    Welcome to TweetMe

    <div id='tweets'></div>

    <script>
        const tweetsElement = document.getElementById('tweets')
        tweetsElement.innerHTML = 'loading...'

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        const method = 'GET'
        const url = 'tweets/'
        const responseType = "json"

        function likeBtn() {
            return '<button class='btn btn-primary'>Like</button>'
        }

        function formatTweetElement(tweet) {
            console.log('HELLO');
            var formattedTweet = `
                <div class="mb-4" id="tweet-id-${tweet.id}">
                    <p>${tweet.user}</p>
                    <p>${tweet.content}</p>
                    ${likeBtn()}
                </div>`;
            console.log(formattedTweet)
            return formattedTweet
        }

        xhr.responseType = responseType
        xhr.open(method, url)
        xhr.onload = function() {
            const serverResponse = xhr.response
            var listedItems = serverResponse.response
            console.log(listedItems)
            var finalTweetStr = ""
            for (i in listedItems) {
                var tweetObj = listedItems[i]
                finalTweetStr += formatTweetElement(tweetObj)
            }
            tweetsElement.innerHTML = finalTweetStr
        }
        xhr.send()
    </script>
{% endblock content %}
```

Please ignore the `{% block content %}` parts, it's valid when rendering in Django.
Can anyone help me with my error? All I know is that there is something wrong in the `<script></script>` section.

Comment: Your "likeBtn" function uses single quotes everywhere so you're closing the string literal too early.

Comment: Unrelated but extracting that to a function seems pointless.

Comment: Dave Newton Thanks a lot! I'm making the button as separate function because I want to add more functionalities to it, and don't want to overcomplicate it.

Comment: Got it. In general, refactoring is a Very Good Thing (I'm accused of too much refactoring). You know your needs better than I do--didn't mean to discourage reasonable refactoring!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in

```
function likeBtn() {
        return '<button class='btn btn-primary'>Like</button>'
    }
```

you use the same kind of quotes.

Use

```
function likeBtn() {
        return '<button class="btn btn-primary">Like</button>'
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot!